# How to set local values for Postgres when calling ExecuteUpdate with EFCore

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have an update command that is taking about 18 seconds when it's run, as Posgres is making a bad choice for it's execution plan.

If I execute

```
set local enable_mergejoin=false;
```

before the update it drops to under 2 seconds. If I switch to executing raw SQL I can disable the mergejoin however I'd like to keep my EF Core code if possible

```
 var query = from ld in dataContext.LoadData
 join i in dataContext.Instances on ld.SettledCurveId equals i.CurveId
 where ld.LoadJobId == loadJobId && i.SettledInstanceId == null
 select new { ld, i };

 var count = await query.ExecuteUpdateAsync(q => q.SetProperty(x => x.ld.SettledInstanceId, x => x.i.Id), cancellationToken);
```

Is there a way I can disable the mergejoin when I call ExecuteUpdateAsync?

Comment: Don't use ORMs like EF Core for this in the first place, especially when you intend to execute database-specific code. EF Core isn't a database driver or library. That's what Npgsql and ADO.NET are. BTW the LINQ code suggests the *entities* don't have relations. There's no need for JOINs in ORMs, the relations are already know or defined.

Comment: For this special scenario there are relation's missing by design in the DB Context which is why we're using an explicit join

Comment: We don;t really want to use database specific code, but Postgres isn't giving us much choice here as 2 seconds vs 18 seconds is too big a difference to ignore

Comment: It's not PostgreSQL, it's the misuse of the ORM. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. ORMs in general, not just EF Core, try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. There are object with properties and collections, not joins. Right now, you're trying to approximate the SQL script you have in mind. Does the *actual* SQL match what you expected though, or does it contain extra constructs that force PostgreSQL do a bad prediction? Missing indexes, missing statistics perhaps?

Comment: The SQL you try to emulate seems simple `UPDATE LoadData SET SettledInstanceId=Instances.ID FROM LoadData LEFT JOIN Instances on SettledCurveID=CurveID Where LoadJobId=@loadJobId AND Instances.SettledInstanceId IS NULL`. What's the execution plan for this? What does the query generated by EF Core look like? If the straightforward SQL has a bad plan, try to fix that instead of hard-coding join strategies. Statistics change and hard-coded strategies are one of the MAJOR causes of unexpected production performance issues.

Comment: Not really, the timing I gave you were from running the SQL generated by EF Core in PgAdmin, so we can trace the time difference down to Postgres choosing to do a mergejoin even though its not as efficient

Comment: You should start from that then. That's the first step in SQL perf troubleshooting. Hard-coded hints may cover up the problem but make fixing *future* problems a lot harder. Next time you won't know *what* hard-code hint may be causing the perf issues. While you could search all functions, stored procedures and views, you won't be able to inspect *clients* that use hard-coded hints

Comment: You should also check what the SQL you're trying to execute *really* looks like. `ExecuteUpdateAsync...` is a convenience method, not a replacement for actual SQL.

Comment: If you really, really insist, you'll have to create a [command interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-command-interception-to-add-query-hints) that issues the extra statements. This complexity isn't a bug. The farther you move from the way ORMs are meant to be used (object graphs magically persisted to tables), the harder things become.